# session gets lost after form submit

Tags: php, html, forms, session, refresh

When a user links to link it redirects to edit.php - here's an example: www.cars.com/edit.php?id=23

In edit.php, I use `_GET` to store the value in a session. The value is stored in `$_session['user']` but when the form on the same page is submitted `echo $_session['user']` displays nothing - how can I make it display the value?.

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 $_session['user']=$_GET['id'];  // I use _GET to store the value in session
if( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  echo $_session['user'];

}

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="formI2D"     enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formI2D" />
```

Comment: Is `session_start()` at the top of *every* page?

Comment: its only one page, and the form gets submitted to the same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're redeclaring your $_SESSION['user'] even when it's a POST (I think).

You can fix this by adding `?id=$_GET['id']` in you form's action, or by wrapping your `$_SESSION` initialisation like that:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     $_SESSION['user']=$_GET['id'];
}
```

Also, you should use uppercase for php global arrays (`$_POST, $_COOKIE, $_SESSION` etc)

Comment: when the form is submited the $_GET['id'] is not submited

Comment: Then use the 2nd solution, or you can also check `if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user']))` instead of `if (isset($_GET['id']))`

Comment: <?php 
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION); it displays the id even after i submit the form, but i cannot get the value if i want to echo them out I cannot 'echo $_session['code']; will not work, but it displays an array Array ( [code] => csci203 )

Comment: You should use $_SESSION instead of $_session

Comment: here is another solution.

<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['code'] =$_GET['id'];
if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {   
echo $_SESSION['code'];
}

<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['code'];?>"/> 
so when the form is submitted the value is also submited

Comment: thank you :) so at the end session will not work over-here right?

Comment: It your code is the one you provided in your previous comment, no : if no id is provided by GET, $_SESSION['code'] will be empty. I think the best solution for your problem is the one I've provided in my answer.